# Why is my TextBox Column in my GridView not found with a FindControl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a GridView that displays correctly. I have a GridView in my aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font="8" />
```

In my code.behind I also have:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then

            Dim boundColumn As BoundField = New BoundField With {
                .HeaderText = "Product Name",
                .DataField = "ProductName"
            }
            GridView1.Columns.Add(boundColumn)

            Dim txtBkWhColumn As TemplateField = New TemplateField With {
                .ItemTemplate = New TextColumn("myTextBox1"),
                .HeaderText = "BK/WH"
            }
            GridView1.Columns.Add(txtBkWhColumn)

            Dim txtBlPuColumn As TemplateField = new TemplateField With {
                .ItemTemplate = new TextColumn("myTextBox2"),
                .HeaderText = "BL/PU"
            }
            GridView1.Columns.Add(txtBlPuColumn)
```

...

```
Class TextColumn
Implements ITemplate

Private ReadOnly _myName As String

Public Sub New(myName As String)
    _myName = myName
End Sub

Public Sub InstantiateIn(container As Control) Implements ITemplate.InstantiateIn
    Dim txt As New TextBox
    txt.ID = _myName
    txt.Columns = 1
    container.Controls.Add(txt)
End Sub
End Class
```

But when I try to read the content of the textbox it is null

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    Debug.WriteLine($"Row {row.Cells(0).Text}")
    Dim bkwh As TextBox = row.Cells(1).FindControl("myTextBox1") 
    Dim blpu As TextBox = row.Cells(2).FindControl("myTextBox2") 

    Dim countBkWh As Int32
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(bkwh.Text)) Then
            countBkWh = Int32.Parse(bkwh.Text)
            Debug.WriteLine($"Count of BLWH: {countBkWh}")
            sb.Append(" " & $"BLWH:{countBkWh}")
            total = total + countBkWh
        End If
```

I get an Null Reference exception on this last if statement saying bkwh is not an instance of an object

Comment: Did you already tried conversion like `Dim bkwh As TextBox = CType(row.Cells(1).FindControl("myTextBox1"), TextBox)`? Probably the `bkwh` contains `Nothing` because `FindControl` didn't cast to `TextBox` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I needed to move my column definitions from Page_Load to Page_Init. I don't why that worked, but it did.